# HTML flicker when above VMR9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web app with an ActiveX that decodes video with FFMPEG and renders the video using VMR9.
for some reason, each time I'm trying to put some HTML (even with IFrame) causes the panel to flicker.

How can I eliminate the flickering?
Maybe it is related to how I initialize the VMR9.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're right...updated

Comment: I'd suggest moving towards HTML5 video if you can... ActiveX is limited to IE, and has a history of causing all kinds of rendering issues when you have it covered up... the rendering pipeline can become confused.  See: requestAnimationFrame depending on how you are doing timing this can be an issue as well.

Comment: I wish I could :-) There are many reasons for why we're using ActiveX and at this point we cannot change that.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the video play normal on your computer?
And for a webapp i recommend to decode in h.264.

Comment: Yes, the video plays fine. I'm using H.264, the problem is not the decoding.
The problem is that I can overlay nothing above the video without having the overlay flickering.